# How does a non-standard string literal avoid a syntax error generated by a standard string literal?

Tags: julia

Based on the [relevant section](https://docs.julialang.org/en/v1/manual/metaprogramming/#Non-Standard-String-Literals-1) of the Julia docs, my understanding is that a non-standard string literal like `foo"hello, world"` is equivalent to explicitly calling the corresponding macro: `@foo_str("hello, world")`. However, there must be some extra magic that I'm not understanding. Consider a date format `dateformat"\m"`. By itself, `"\m"` throws a syntax error:

```
julia> "\m"
ERROR: syntax: invalid escape sequence
```

And the same syntax error is thrown if I call `@dateformat_str("\m")`, since the string literal `"\m"` appears to be evaluated or error checked before it is passed to the macro:

```
julia> using Dates

julia> @dateformat_str("\m")
ERROR: syntax: invalid escape sequence
```

However, using the non-standard string literal works:

```
julia> dateformat"\m"
dateformat"\m"
```

This is counter-intuitive, because I thought that `dateformat"\m"` was equivalent to `@dateformat_str("\m")`. How does the non-standard string literal avoid the syntax error generated by the standard string literal?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In short, because the parser recognizes that situation and parses the string literal differently

For string macros invocations [it does this](https://github.com/JuliaLang/julia/blob/9a1dbc038587c6072ac99699e416cbc8908054ed/src/julia-parser.scm#L1241-L1244).
Calling: `parse-raw-literal`

Where as for normal string literals [it does this](https://github.com/JuliaLang/julia/blob/9a1dbc038587c6072ac99699e416cbc8908054ed/src/julia-parser.scm#L2330).
Calling `parse-string-literal`

---

`@dateformat_str("\m")` on the other hand parses as a macro invocation on a normal string literal. so it uses the later `parse-string-literal`, which errors.

Note that ones parsed it has parsed the string into what is escaped as `"\\m"`

```
julia> dump(:(dateformat"\m"))
Expr
  head: Symbol macrocall
  args: Array{Any}((3,))
    1: Symbol @dateformat_str
    2: LineNumberNode
      line: Int64 1
      file: Symbol REPL[6]
    3: String "\\m
```

---

Of related interest is  the raw string macro , which does nothing at all, but is still going to be string parsed using `parse-raw-literal`
It is basically defined as

```
macro raw_str(s)
    return s
end
```

Comment: Thanks! Though `@dateformat_str(raw"\m")` doesn't appear to work, since `raw"\m"` gets passed into the macro as an expression and `DateFormat` doesn't have a method for `::Expr`.